# How to get image links from the firebase storage

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-storage

I have uploaded the images on the firebase storage and have set the rules to be all public.

I wish to get the links to the images in different folders but am unable to figure out how to proceed in Go. There are tons of tutorials of getting images in Java/Python/JavaScript but not many in Go unfortunately.

This is my code so far:

```
bucketName := "<bucket-id>.appspot.com"
    
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithoutAuthentication())

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return nil, err
}

bucket := client.Bucket(bucketName)
```

In this bucket, I have some directories, let's say I want to get the images from `dirOne`. How do I proceed for this from here or is this the wrong way to request files from firebase storage?

Comment: What those tutorials on Java/Python/JavaScript suggest to do in your case? I'm asking becaue with high certainity the API provided by whatever package(s) you're using to access firebird (whatever that means) is not too different from the API for other imperative programming languages. So you basically look how it's done elsewhere and then expore the APIs provided for Go, looking for the same/alike data types and methods.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a firebase project, in the GCP project will be added automatically a bucket for that firebase project. So you can use [gcs go package](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage) to interact with your firebase files.

**Listing files of a folder**

```
it := client.Bucket(bucket).Objects(ctx, &storage.Query{
    Prefix:    prefix,
    Delimiter: delim,
})
for {
    attrs, err := it.Next()
    if err == iterator.Done {
            break
    }
    if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Bucket(%q).Objects(): %v", bucket, err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, attrs.Name)
}
return nil
```

Let's say you want to retrieve all files in images folder. The prefix should be /images and delim /.

**Are you going to send these files back to frontend? If that's the case please read following recommendation**

In case you need to send files to the frontend, the current approach is inefficient as the files will go through your backend and this is not scalable in terms of performance. You may store the files relative url to the firebase database and send them to the frontend. After that the frontend can request them directly using http request.